# Xcode 4.1 multi-touch gestures changed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4

Just upgraded to Xcode 4.1 (and Lion).

Does anyone know what the gesture is for 'Jump to Next Counterpart' (or a reference for the gestures)? It switches between the header and implementation file.
It was the 3-finger swipe up / down, but now the OS is using that gesture.

The accelerator keys are Control+Command + up arrow (from the Navigate menu).

Comment: I found the fix to this issue here: https://gist.github.com/1132018

Answer (score 1):

It's 2-finger swipe left and right. In your .h file, swipe 2 FINGERS LEFT to go to the .m. In your .m file, swipe 2 FINGERS RIGHT to go to the .h.

(Really strange update indeed)

Comment: Actually the 2 fingers right is "Back" and 2 fingers left is "Forward" (relative to your file history in the editor) much like the new Safari. Very useful gestures indeed, but not quite what the poster was asking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The 2 finger left/right history swipe almost doesn't frustrate the hell out me... until I hit a xib file and the screen pans instead of paging, or I forget where I am in the chain. 'Reseting' the history by clicking through the files I'm actually going to use doesn't seem very efficient, so I was hoping someone knew what this gesture was (hopefully) changed to. Seems too useful to get outright dropped.

Comment: Thanks George, I didn't realize that. Did some testing and even after turning off the 3-finger gesture for Mission Control (in System Prefs), it still doesn't work in XCode. Hope they fix it with an update.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping to counterpart is now performed using a four-finger swipe either upwards or downwards. As before it seems to just oscillate between the two files. Hope this helps...

Comment: Four finger swipe up/down keeps zooming me out to Mission Control. Were there any other settings you adjusted to get this behavior?

Comment: Not that I recall - but as |_h2o_| says in his answer I am using a Magic Trackpad.
Might be worth checking in System Preferences>Trackpad that Mission Control is not set to 4 finger gesture - assume that would override any app specific behaviour

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the four finger gesture to change between the header and implementation file only works on a Magic trackpad